# How to disable Parallel Master Port Address pins in PIC32

Tags: pic, pins

I am using `PIC32MX795F512L` MCU. I need to use few GPIOs on which `Parallel Master Port Address` pins are already defined like in `Pin44 Pin43` `PMA0` and `PMA1` is defined . So to use these as GPIO input I need to disable their functionality. I tried setting their ON bit as low but this doesn't help.

Need help in disabling the PMP pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PIC32 Reference Manual describes how to do this using the PMCON register. From the manual:

[image: manual01]

The content of the register is described as follows, see the highlighted section in red:

[image: manual02]

If you have already set the ON bit low, then the functionality should revert to "normal". What's not so clear, but is buried in the reference manual, is that you also need to clear the PMAEN register:

[image: pmaen1]

[image: pmaen]

However, having done that, it's possible that the pins you want to use are also affected by other peripherals and you may need to map inputs/outputs via PPS.

The pins you refer to are RD9 and RD10 in that device. The datasheet shows which other peripherals can use those pins:

[image: RD9_10]

Comment: Well thanks for this useful information. I am using PIC32MX795F512L.